# Nvidia driver broken after a full system update on Arch Linux

Tags: nvidia

after a full system update (`pacman -Syu`), I can no longer use my nvidia card on my optimus laptop. Here is my hardware:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep '\[03'    
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [8086:3e9b]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] [10de:1c20] (rev a1)
```

I use the official nvidia driver from the arch repository. Running `nvidia-smi` give me the following:

```
$ nvidia-smi      
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Any idea what I should do ?

Edit: My pacman.log file:

```
[2018-12-20 18:51] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu'
[2018-12-20 18:51] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2018-12-20 18:51] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] running '70-dkms-remove.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> dkms remove bbswitch/0.8 -k 4.19.8-arch1-1-ARCH
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> dkms remove openrazer-driver/2.4.0 -k 4.19.8-arch1-1-ARCH
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] transaction started
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] removed archlabs-user-skel (1.7.21-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-common (1.3.5-1 -> 1.3.7-2)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-dARK (1.0-1 -> 1.0-2)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-icons (1.2-1 -> 1.2-2)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-keyring (2018.06.09-1 -> 2018.12.13-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Appending keys from archlabs.gpg...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Locally signing trusted keys in keyring...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key AEFB411B072836CD48FF0381AE252C284B5DBA5D...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key 9E4F11C6A072942A7B3FD3B0B81EB14A09A25EB0...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key 35F52A02854DCCAEC9DD5CC410443C7F54B00041...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Importing owner trust values...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Updating trust database...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] gpg: next trustdb check due at 2019-03-29
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded glib2 (2.58.1+67+g17519e039-1 -> 2.58.2-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded gtk-update-icon-cache (3.24.2+1+g2905fc861a-1 -> 3.24.2+7+g43aeb52b73-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded libsystemd (239.303-1 -> 239.370-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded e2fsprogs (1.44.4-1 -> 1.44.5-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded dbus (1.12.10-2 -> 1.12.12-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded systemd (239.303-1 -> 239.370-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] warning: directory permissions differ on /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/
filesystem: 755  package: 750
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded polkit (0.115+3+g8638ec5-1 -> 0.115+24+g5230646-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded llvm-libs (7.0.0-2 -> 7.0.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded libinput (1.12.3-1 -> 1.12.4-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded nvidia-utils (415.23-1 -> 415.25-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] If you run into trouble with CUDA not being available, run nvidia-modprobe first.
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded gtk3 (3.24.2+1+g2905fc861a-1 -> 3.24.2+7+g43aeb52b73-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-kickshaw (0.6.4-1 -> 0.6.4-3)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded libnghttp2 (1.34.0-1 -> 1.35.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-networkmanager-dmenu (58.2-1 -> 58.2-2)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-oblogout (0.2.5-1 -> 0.2.6-2)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-paranoid (1.2-1 -> 1.2-2)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-pipemenus (2.6.18-1 -> 2.6.30-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-polybar (3.2.0-1 -> 3.2.1-5)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-skippy-xd (1.0-1 -> 1.0-2)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-themes (1.5.1-1 -> 1.5.3-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlabs-wallpapers (1.5.1-1 -> 1.5.2-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded archlinux-keyring (20181128-1 -> 20181218-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Appending keys from archlinux.gpg...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Locally signing trusted keys in keyring...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key DDB867B92AA789C165EEFA799B729B06A680C281...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key 684148BB25B49E986A4944C55184252D824B18E8...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key 91FFE0700E80619CEB73235CA88E23E377514E00...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key AB19265E5D7D20687D303246BA1DFB64FFF979E7...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key 0E8B644079F599DFC1DDC3973348882F6AC6A4C2...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Importing owner trust values...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Disabling revoked keys in keyring...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 7FA647CD89891DEDC060287BB9113D1ED21E1A55...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key D4DE5ABDE2A7287644EAC7E36D1A9E70E19DAA50...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 40440DC037C05620984379A6761FAD69BA06C6A9...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key B1F2C889CB2CCB2ADA36D963097D629E437520BD...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 5357F3B111688D88C1D88119FCF2CB179205AC90...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 5559BC1A32B8F76B3FCCD9555FA5E5544F010D48...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key BC1FBE4D2826A0B51E47ED62E2539214C6C11350...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 63F395DE2D6398BBE458F281F2DBB4931985A992...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 8F76BEEA0289F9E1D3E229C05F946DED983D4366...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 4FCF887689C41B09506BE8D5F3E1D5C5D30DB0AD...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key FB871F0131FEA4FB5A9192B4C8880A6406361833...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 81D7F8241DB38BC759C80FCE3A726C6170E80477...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 5E7585ADFF106BFFBBA319DC654B877A0864983E...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 50F33E2E5B0C3D900424ABE89BDCF497A4BBCC7F...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key E7210A59715F6940CF9A4E36A001876699AD6E84...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 65EEFE022108E2B708CBFCF7F9E712E59AF5F22A...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key F5A361A3A13554B85E57DDDAAF7EF7873CFD4BB6...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 40776A5221EF5AD468A4906D42A1DB15EC133BAD...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 8CF934E339CAD8ABF342E822E711306E3C4F88BC...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 5696C003B0854206450C8E5BE613C09CB4440678...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 5A2257D19FF7E1E0E415968CE62F853100F0D0F0...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 9515D8A8EAB88E49BB65EDBCE6B456CAF15447D5...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 4A8B17E20B88ACA61860009B5CED81B7C2E5C0D2...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 0B20CA1931F5DA3A70D0F8D2EA6836E1AB441196...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 34C5D94FE7E7913E86DC427E7FB1A3800C84C0A5...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 39F880E50E49A4D11341E8F939E4F17F295AFBF4...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 66BD74A036D522F51DD70A3C7F2A16726521E06D...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 07DFD3A0BC213FA12EDC217559B3122E2FA915EC...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 44D4A033AC140143927397D47EFD567D4C7EA887...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 27FFC4769E19F096D41D9265A04F9397CDFD6BB0...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 8840BD07FC24CB7CE394A07CCF7037A4F27FB7DA...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Updating trust database...
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] gpg: next trustdb check due at 2019-03-29
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded linux-firmware (20181026.1cb4e51-1 -> 20181218.0f22c85-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded linux (4.19.8.arch1-1 -> 4.19.10.arch1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded b43-firmware (6.30.163.46-1 -> 6.30.163.46-2)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> If you encounter problems with v6.30, try the 'b43-firmware-classic' package (v5.100) instead.
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded bbswitch-dkms (0.8-184 -> 0.8-186)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded broadcom-wl (6.30.223.271-65 -> 6.30.223.271-67)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded compiler-rt (7.0.0-2 -> 7.0.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded clang (7.0.0-1 -> 7.0.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded conky (1.11.0-1 -> 1.11.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded poppler (0.71.0-1 -> 0.72.0-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded libmagick (7.0.8.16-1 -> 7.0.8.19-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded imagemagick (7.0.8.16-1 -> 7.0.8.19-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded cups-filters (1.21.5-1 -> 1.21.6-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded electron (3.0.11-1 -> 3.0.13-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded geany (1.33.0-2 -> 1.34-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded git (2.20.0-1 -> 2.20.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded glib2-docs (2.58.1+67+g17519e039-1 -> 2.58.2-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded libassuan (2.5.1-1 -> 2.5.2-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded gnupg (2.2.11-1 -> 2.2.12-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded libmagick6 (6.9.10.16-1 -> 6.9.10.17-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded poppler-glib (0.71.0-1 -> 0.72.0-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded inkscape (0.92.3-6 -> 0.92.3-7)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-systemd (239.300-1 -> 239.370-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-dbus (1.12.10-1 -> 1.12.12-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-e2fsprogs (1.44.4-1 -> 1.44.5-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-glib2 (2.58.1-1 -> 2.58.2-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-nettle (3.4-1 -> 3.4.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-gnutls (3.5.19-2 -> 3.6.5-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-llvm-libs (7.0.0-1 -> 7.0.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-nvidia-utils (415.23-1 -> 415.25-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded libsynctex (2018.48691-1 -> 2018.48691-3)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded libuv (1.24.0-1 -> 1.24.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded libxnvctrl (415.22-1 -> 415.25-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded linux-headers (4.19.8.arch1-1 -> 4.19.10.arch1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded linux-lts (4.14.88-1 -> 4.14.89-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded nodejs (11.4.0-1 -> 11.5.0-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded nvidia (415.23-1 -> 415.25-2)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded nvidia-lts (1:415.23-1 -> 1:415.25-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded nvidia-settings (415.22-1 -> 415.25-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded openmp (7.0.0-1 -> 7.0.1-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded parallel (20180822-1 -> 20181122-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded python-six (1.11.0-3 -> 1.12.0-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded python-mako (1.0.7-2 -> 1.0.7-3)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded python-raven (6.9.0-2 -> 6.10.0-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded python2-six (1.11.0-3 -> 1.12.0-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded qemu (3.0.0-4 -> 3.1.0-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded systemd-sysvcompat (239.303-1 -> 239.370-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded telegram-desktop (1.5.1-3 -> 1.5.2-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded texlive-bin (2018.48691-1 -> 2018.48691-3)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded vala (0.42.3-2 -> 0.42.4-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded virtualbox-host-modules-arch (5.2.22-10 -> 5.2.22-12)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded wget (1.19.5-1 -> 1.20-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] upgraded xterm (337-1 -> 340-1)
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2018-12-20 18:53] [ALPM] running '60-linux-lts.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running '60-linux.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running '70-dkms-install.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> dkms install bbswitch/0.8 -k 4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> dkms install openrazer-driver/2.4.0 -k 4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Unable to install module openrazer-driver/2.4.0 for kernel 4.14.89-1-lts: Missing kernel headers.
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Unable to install module bbswitch/0.8 for kernel 4.14.89-1-lts: Missing kernel headers.
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running '90-linux-lts.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux-lts.preset: 'default'
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux-lts.img
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Starting build: 4.14.89-1-lts
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [base]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [udev]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [modconf]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [block]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [shutdown]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [fsck]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Generating module dependencies
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux-lts.img
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Image generation successful
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux-lts.preset: 'fallback'
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img -S autodetect
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Starting build: 4.14.89-1-lts
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [base]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [udev]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [modconf]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [block]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: wd719x
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: aic94xx
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [shutdown]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [fsck]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Generating module dependencies
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Image generation successful
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running '90-linux.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset: 'default'
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux.img
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Starting build: 4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [base]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [udev]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [modconf]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [block]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [shutdown]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [fsck]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Generating module dependencies
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Image generation successful
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset: 'fallback'
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img -S autodetect
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Starting build: 4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [base]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [udev]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [modconf]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [block]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: wd719x
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: aic94xx
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [shutdown]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [fsck]
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Generating module dependencies
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Image generation successful
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'detect-old-perl-modules.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'glib-compile-schemas.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'gtk-query-immodules-3.0.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'gtk-update-icon-cache.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'mktexlsr.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'systemd-catalog.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'systemd-daemon-reload.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'systemd-hwdb.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'systemd-sysctl.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'systemd-sysusers.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'systemd-tmpfiles.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'systemd-udev-reload.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'systemd-update.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'texinfo-install.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:54] [ALPM] running 'texlive-fmtutil.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:55] [ALPM] running 'texlive-updmap.hook'...
[2018-12-20 18:55] [ALPM] running 'update-desktop-database.hook'...
```

Comment: Downgrade and try again?

Comment: How is it possible to revert a full system upgrade ?

Comment: Did the packages upgraded include the kernel/modules, and if so, have you rebooted?

Comment: I uploaded the pacman log file. Yes I did a reboot after.